# Adobe Acrobat X Pro - Export PDF to Text accessible

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0

I'm in a PDF reading project through C # 2012 with Aspose. But I'm struggling to read pages that have several columns.

For example, a PDF can have on page 1 (one) and two columns on page 3 (three) and 5 columns in the sixth page onwards have only one (1) column.

I can not previously know which page will come and how many columns.

I thought about using the SDK ADOBE ACROBAT X PRO to export in handy .txt (with page break marker), but do not know if it's the best solution.

Using the SAVE AS (not via sdk) Acrobat realized that does not export correctly, am I doing something wrong?

Which can guide me?

PS: I used iTextSharp initially, however Aspose proved to be an extremely better tool than iTextSharp.

Comment: I think you are out of luck with this one, in general there is no such thing as "columns" in a PDF file, inside PDF, you just get a sequence of drawing instructions, for example: "put this character at (3,4), this other one at (10,15), etc", at the end you get something that "looks" like text formatted in columns. Most text extraction tools will try to guess "words", sentences and paragraphs from that, but expecting them to find columns of text as well is probably too much.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tested the tool "PDFMATE" which could "discover" correctly the various columns, however, does not exist SDK this tool for me to insert into my project. I will continue looking for ...